# LinkedHashMap.clear() occasionally throws NullPointerException on Android

Tags: android

A class has only one place to set mapFoo:

```
final private LinkedHashMap<EnumA, ClassA> mapFoo= new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

There is only one place where an entry is added to mapFoo

```
mapFoo.put(enumA, new ClassA());
```

The following code

```
mapFoo.clear()
```

occasionally throws the following exception:

```
Class: java.lang.NullPointerException
 Stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry.nxt' on a null object reference
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.clear(LinkedHashMap.java:327)
```

How is this possible? I want to emphasize this is very rare. I thought there would be zero chance for this to happen. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Is it possible that there's more than one thread accessing that map at once? Because that class is not defined to be thread safe and concurrent access can cause all kinds of unexpected behaviour (including "impossible" NullPointerException).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you for the tip. Yes, it is possible though I try to avoid it. I tested your hypothesis by creating 100 threads to execute mapFoo.clear() incessantly and ran a few minutes without luck.  Wonder if this is device dependent. I am testing on a tablet. The latest instance of this exception happened on an Android TV box. Android TV box is prone to issues.

Comment: If it is a multi-threading issue, then you're most likely to reproduce it if you have a mixture of adding/removing/iterating/getting specific items/clearing happening in your test. Just calling `clear` from many threads on a map that's usually empty is unlikely to cause the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Since it is very rare and the exception is caught, I will live with it.